# Сохранение переменной при двойном post

Tags: php, jquery

Возникла проблема с сохранением переменной. Есть файл Index.php, с него ajax'ом методом POST отправляется на файл catalog.php переменная, затем благодаря этому файлику создается папка этим именем. Затем на index.php нажимается еще одна кнопка, благодаря ей должны сохраняться картинки в папку, которую только что создал, но этого не происходит, так как переменная, которая за это отвечает `$catalog = "Catalog/".$_POST["saveFolder"]."/";` выглядит как Catalog//, т.е. `$_POST["saveFolder"]` пустой. Пробовал различными способами сохранять, но так и не вышло ничего, перезаписывается переменная. Есть ли способ обуздать сию проблему?)

Сессии использовал, не получается все равно. Очень нужна помощь. Если что, могу предоставить полный код файлов, он не большой.

**Обновление**

На странице index.php запустил сессию. Затем, когда в инпут ввел имя папки и нажал "ок", значение поля передалось в файл catalog.php, где создалась папка. Затем, выбрал картинки какие хочу загрузить и нажал upload. Идем в скрипт upload.php, где сохраняем в созданную папку. Это значение созданной папки должно где-то сохраниться, чтобы не потерялось.
В catalog.php я вот так сессию использовал

```
$_SESSION['fldr'] = $_POST['saveFolder'];
$safe = $_SESSION['fldr'];
echo $safe;
$catalog = "Catalog/".$safe."/";
echo "this is folder".$safe."!";
```

Но выдает

> Notice: Undefined index in catalog.php

Пытался ввести проверку на пустое значение `if (isset($_POST['saveFolder'])) $a = $_POST['saveFolder'];`, но выдает такое

> Notice: Undefined variable: a

Comment: Не забудь сделать переданному каталогу basename() хотя бы. А то тебе насоздают...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Сессии использовал, не получается все равно.

Надо попробовать еще раз.

Потому что "перезаписывается POST" - это [**нормальное**](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke) поведение.
А для сохранения состояния между запросами как раз должны использоваться сессии.
Поэтому надо не "пытаться обуздать" заведомо нерешаемую проблему, отмахиваясь от единственно правильного решения, а исправлять свои ошибки.

При использовании сессий **всегда** должна вызываться команда  `session_start()`.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ты точно прочел последнее предложение моего ответа?

Comment: да, прочел. А если я напишу так: `$_SESSION['fldr'] = $_POST['saveFolder'];`, разве сессионная переменная не будет каждый раз перезаписываться?

Comment: Ну так писать надо с умом, только тода когда надо. У тебя на все посты один и тот же обработчик, что ли? Авторизация ли, создание каталога, заливка файлов - везде один и тот же код что ли все время выполняется, лишь бы пост был?

Comment: Все что мне нужно - это чтобы переменная сначала поучаствовала в одном скрипте, сохранилась, а затем поучаствовала в третьем скрипте. Извиняюсь, если что-то не так пишу, голова уже пухнет от всего этого. Вроде задачка простая, а решить не получается.

Comment: А зачем ты ее в другом скрипте сам же и перезаписываешь?

Comment: а чего не создать один скрипт либо в одном последовательность из нескольких?либо передавай параметр в пост запросе. Или ты не хочешь,что б его смогли подставить злые хакеры или что именно?

Comment: @Ипатьев, спасибо, все верно было сказано. Проблема была только с моей стороны. Все решил сессиями.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сперва создаете элемент,потом добавляете ему картинку?я правильно понял?просто не оч понятно.
допустим вы создаете статью про автомобиль-папка будет выглядеть lada-2109 например либо лучше айди присвоить. Отправляете данные- создаете папку с таким именем либо с Id статьи. И сервер выдает ответ джейсоном,например {id:123,Name:"lada-2109"} таким образом вы будете знать,что отослать нужно на id 123 .
Можно и через сессии. Просто,может вы неверно сохранили.поэкспериментируйте просто с обычн значениями записать/прочитать.

Comment: Базы не нужно использовать. Здесь надо как в apple, чтобы все просто)

Answer (score -1):

можете каталог хранить в куках... При создании папочки - создавать кук, при загрузке файлов - считывать кук.

Comment: Для сохранения внутренних переменных сервера всегда должны использоваться только сессии.

Answer (score -1):

Ну как вариант, можно при первой отправке имя созданной папки сохранять в `<input type="hidden" name="folderName" />`. А следующий запрос который будет отправляться, уже будет содержать `folderName` с каким либо значением. Логика проста, не надо использовать всякие сессии и т.д. Но это все будет работать в рамках, пока ты не обновишь страницу полностью. Хорошо можно сделать с помощью бд. Создаешь папку, она записывается в бд, ты выбираешь в какую папку загрузить, имя этой папки заполняется в `<input name="folderName" />` и ты уже с ней работаешь. Это как вариант правильного подхода для твоей задачи.